# .NET 3.5 C# StreamReader Reading ISO-8859-1 Characters Incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, streamreader, latin

In summary I retrieve a HTTP Web Response containing JSON formatted data with unicode characters such as "\u00c3\u00b1" which should translate to "ñ". Instead these characters are converted to "Ã±" by the JSON parser I am using. The behavior I'm looking for is for those characters to be translated to "ñ".

Taking the following code and executing it...

```
string nWithAccent = "\u00c3\u00b1";

Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1");
byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(nWithAccent);

nWithAccent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBytes);
```

nWithAccent outputs "ñ". This is the result I am looking for. I took the above code and used it on the "response_body" variable below which contained the same characters as above (from what I could see using the Visual Studio 2008 Text Analyzer) and did not get the same result... it does nothing with the characters "\u00c3\u00b1".

In my application I execute the following code against an external system retrieving data in JSON format. Upon examining the "response_body" variable using the text analyzer in Visual Studio I see "\u00c3\u00b1" instead of ñ. E.g. the word "niño" would be seen in the Text Analyzer as "ni\u00c3\u00b1o".

```
using (HttpWResponse = (HttpWebResponse)this.HttpWRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpWResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        // token will expire 60 min from now.
        this.TimeTillTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);

        // read response data
        response_body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I then use an open source JSON parser which replaces "\u00c3" with "Ã" and "\u00b1" with "±" with an end result of "Ã±" instead of "ñ". Is something wrong with the JSON parser or am I applying the wrong encoding to the response stream? The headers in the response indicate the charset as being UTF-8. Thanks for any replies!

Comment: What happens if you encode 'response_body' before running the JSON parser?

Comment: In order to investigate whether StreamReader is "reading ISO-8859-1 characters incorrectly", it would be necessary to know the **exact** bytes coming over the wire. I also *personally* find it a bit confusing that you are encoding a string from 8859-1, and decoding it as UTF-8... or is that just a mechanism to set up the bytes? Arguably, since you are decoding with UTF-8, the question of how it handles 8859-1 is completely moot?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Marc, what is coming over the line according to the "charset" header is encoding of "UTF-8". I simply experimented with ISO-8859-1 to see what kind of results I got. The characters should come in as UTF-8 then be outputted to a webpage in UTF-8 as well. I really shouldn't have to do any conversion except maybe HTML Encode the raw text for accented characters. Due to the fact that the ñ in this scenario is being represented with 2 escaped sequences it messes things up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response you are receiving is invalid. `"\u00c3\u00b1"` isn't the correct encoding for `ñ`.

Instead it's a sort of double encoding. It has first been encoded as an UTF-8 byte sequence and then the bytes above 128 have been escaped with the `\u` sequence.

Since a JSON response is usally UTF-8 anyway, there's no need to escape the two byte sequence for `ñ`. If escaping is used, it must not be applied to the two byte sequence but rather to the single Unicode character itself. It would then result in `"\u00f1"`.

You can test it with an online JSON validator (such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) or [JSON Format](http://jsonformat.com/)) by pasting the following JSON data:

```
{
    "unescaped": "ñ",
    "escaped": "\u00f1",
    "wrong": "\u00c3\u00b1"
}
```

Comment: Is there any feasible way to handle this or am I best off to just notify the sender of the data and hope they fix it someday?

Comment: I'd certainly contact the sender so they fix it. Whether you can fix in your code (as a short term solution) is difficult to say without seeing full samples of JSON data. If correct and incorrect encodings are mixed, it's probably not possible. If it's consistently wrong, then you can write a special stream wrapper/filter that works on bytes (and not characters), looks for `\u00nn` and replaces it with the corresponding byte.

Comment: Ya, something is definitely off with what they are sending me. I think I'll get in touch with the sender. I feel confident I can say it is not something wrong on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
new StreamReader(HttpWResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
```

with

```
new StreamReader(HttpWResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1")))
```

Comment: I tried this drdigit. It still comes across as 2 escaped characters \u00c3\u00b1 which are then treated by the JSON parser as 2 separate characters. It is peculiar though that when I instantiate a new string with the 2 escaped characters "\u00c3\u00b" and encode using "ISO8859-1" it works but not when using the same encoding directly on the StreamReader. See my first code block above.

Comment: Sorry missed a 1 after the b in "\u00c3\u00b". It was "\u00c3\u00b1".

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you pass this string to the JSON parser?

```
string s = "\\u00c3\\u00b1";
```

I suspect you'll get `"Ã±"`.

Is there a way you can tell your JSON parser to interpret characters in the string as though they're UTF-8 bytes?

You're probably better off reading raw bytes from the response stream and passing that to the JSON parser.

I think the problem is that you're converting the raw bytes to a string, which contains the encoded characters. The JSON parser doesn't know if you want that "\u00c3\u00b1" converted to a single UTF-8 character, or two characters.

Comment: I had to pass in the string "{\"test\":\"\\u00c3\\u00b1\"}" in order for it to parse and it returned "Ã±".